# IntelliJ show Git annotated files

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-blame

Is there a way/window to display the list of files that was Git annotated?

Apparently, have forgotten to switch-off the feature when closing the editor from the specific coding session thus the annotate icon is displaying before the module name on project explorer.

Comment: u tried search in path ctrl + shift + F ??? give project root as the path??

Comment: Under what parameters?

Comment: aren't they have any annotated text??

Comment: I think we're misaligned, to GIT annotate a file is down by action **Annotate** which falls under the Git/History category. This is somewhat similar with `git blame` but displayed on the IntelliJ editor

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA does not show any annotate icons in project view. I think what you have there is a bookmark, which you can toggle using Navigate | Bookmarks | Toggle Bookmark